# How to index character in string from a list c++

Tags: c++, string, list, char

I am trying to index a char in a string from a list of strings.

if stringV is a vector this works:

```
vector<string> stringV;

for (int i = 0; i < stringL.size(); i++) {
    if(stringV[i][0] == 'a')
        cout << stringV[i] << endl;
}
```

but if stringL is a list it does not work:

```
list<string> stringL;

for (list<string>::iterator it = stringL.begin(); it != stringL.end(); it++) {
    if (*it[0] == 'a')
        cout << *it << endl;
}
```

neither does this work:

```
for (list<string>::iterator it = stringL.begin(); it != stringL.end(); it++) {
    if (*it.at(0) == 'a')
        cout << *it << endl;
}
```

These are my header files:

```
include <string>
include <list>
include <vector>
```

The reason I am using a list instead of a vector is so that I can insert middle elements more efficiently. Any suggestions on how I index a character from a string in a list?

Comment: How is `stringV` defined?  (Edit your question with the answer.)

Comment: stringV is a vector (edited my question)

Comment: In your first example, how is `stringV` related to `stringL`? You are using `stringL` indexes to access `stringV` elements.  Or did you mean to use `stringV.size()` instead of `stringL.size()`?

Comment: Try using parenthesis:  `if ((*it)[0] == '1')`.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews this also works, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `*it.at(0)` use `(*it).at(0)` or `it->at(0)`.

The expression `*it.at(0)` parses as `*(it.at(0))`, which is meaningless: a `char` can't be dereferenced.